# Listing Items in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm having some trouble creating a list of items in Haskell for a text based adventure game.

```
("cavern",
Room.Room { Room.name = "Cavern"
     , Room.description = ""
     , Room.directions = Map.fromList [
         (North, "hall") ]
     , Room.visited = False
     , Room.items = [
         Item.Item { Item.name = "Trident" } ]
     })
```

Is the code and i'm trying to add multiple items to a room however nothing I've tried seems to work the closest I got was using

```
("cavern",
Room.Room { Room.name = "Cavern"
     , Room.description = ""
     , Room.directions = Map.fromList [
         (North, "hall") ]
     , Room.visited = False
     , Room.items = [
         Item.Item { Item.name = "Trident" } { Item.name = "Trident2" } ]
     })
```

But this just made it so the last item block was the only item in the room

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what's going on here, but if you want a list with 2 items, they have to be comma-separated. Try `Room.items = [Item.Item { Item.name = "Trident" }, Item.Item { Item.name = "Trident2" }`.

Comment: In a list, you separate items with a comma, as in `[1, 2, 3]`. I'm not sure what `[ Item.Item { Item.name = "Trident" } { Item.name = "Trident2" } ]` ever means, but it's not a list of two items.

Comment: It's record syntax for updating the value with a new field.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `Item.Item` is the name of a data constructor with record syntax, you simply need to use it twice.

```
Room.items = [
   Item.Item { Item.name = "Trident" }, Item.Item { Item.name = "Trident2" }
]
```